# Hello world compile error with stlport and Digital Mars

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, windows-7

I'm jumping into C++ and I've fallen at the first hurdle.

I've got a simple hello world:

```
// #include <iostream>
int main()
{
// std::cout <<"This actually works!" << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

I can compile this with Digital Mars using

`\dm\bin\dmc hello`

However, if I uncomment the two lines and try to get the iostream to work with

`\dm\bin\dmc hello -I\dm\stlport\stlport` I get the following error:

```
template <int _Is> struct __bool2type {
         ^
\dm\stlport\stlport\stl/type_traits.h(68) : Error: '=', ';' or ',' expected
};
^
\dm\stlport\stlport\stl/type_traits.h(70) : Error: identifier or '( declarator )' expected
_STLP_TEMPLATE_NULL
                  ^
\dm\stlport\stlport\stl/type_traits.h(72) : Error: '=', ';' or ',' expected
struct __bool2type<1> { typedef __true_type _Ret; };
                                                  ^
\dm\stlport\stlport\stl/type_traits.h(73) : Error: identifier or '( declarator )' expected
_STLP_TEMPLATE_NULL
                  ^
\dm\stlport\stlport\stl/type_traits.h(75) : Error: '=', ';' or ',' expected
Fatal error: too many errors
--- errorlevel 1`
```

I've put the extra stlport folder in dm\stlport\stlport

My SC.INI is as follows:
[Version]
version=7.51 Build 020

```
[Environment]
PATH=%PATH%;"%@P%\..\bin"
BIN="%@P%\..\bin"
INCLUDE="%@P%\..\stlport\stlport";"%@P%\..\include";"%@P%\..\mfc\include";%INCLUDE%
LIB="%@P%\..\lib";"%@P%\..\mfc\lib";%LIB%
HELP="%@P%\..\help"
```

Comment: How upto date / what C++ Standard does `Digital Mars` support ?  From their website it liiks like C++0x which is pre C++11 ie 10+years old. see https://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/CPP0x-Language-Implementation.html  You would be better off with a more modern compiler if possible.

Comment: dmc is a C compiler. You need to invoke dmc++.

Comment: Rename your source file from `hello` to `hello.cpp` and try again.  And although I love Digital Mars to pieces and think Walter Bright is incredible, the Digital Mars C++ compiler has not kept up with modern C++.  Ergo, I suggest you use a compiler that has kept up with the C++ standard as the standard continues to evolve.

Comment: I'm always curious at how someone decides to get into this language and stumble upon such abysmal tools. I had never even heard of this one. And visiting the website I see how. It's main focus isn't even C++.

Comment: @sweenish • Walter Bright wrote the first C++ compiler.  (The other C++ "compilers" at that time were *transpilers* that converted from C++ to C.)

Comment: I knew about the transpilers, my knowledge of C++ history is very "broad strokes." That's cool about this suite, then. But there is definitely a reason it doesn't come up in searches and why I've never heard of it.

Comment: @sweenish • Agreed.  Using Digital Mars C++ is in the same category as "jumping into C++" in 2021 and using the Turbo C++ compiler or Lattice C++ compiler or SAS/C++ compiler.  (I've used all of those.)

Comment: @sweenish Blind luck really. Plus I was looking for a compiler without an IDE or massive footprint. Plus I have no idea what to look for in a compiler at this point in time.

Comment: @GhoulFool we are not supposed to recommend tools but if you let us know your platform / OS and any restrictions (eg low memory etc) I am sure someone will link some up to date free C++ compilers in the comments.

Comment: @RichardCritten As I'm starting out, something that'll work straight out of the box, no IDE, low memory, and "modern" and reliable enough on Win7.

Comment: minGW via [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) is the most likely winner here. That will get you a modern g++. Then write the code wherever, notepad++, sublime text, VS Code, etc.

Comment: @sweenish That looks like a winner! 

Comment: Just FYI, the main three compilers currently are gcc, clang, and cl.exe (MSVC). gcc and clang can be had without an IDE (clang less so on Windows), MSVC ships with full Visual Studio, but it is possible to just get the C++ tools. You would then have to muck around with special terminals and it's generally been a headache whenever I tried to get that going.